# How to plot multiple graphs with "plot_ly" function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put on the same graph multiple lines with the `plot_ly` function from the plotly package. I've used the `lapply` function unsuccessfully once the plots were separated. Follows the code and steps that I used:

First, the sample is generated and put in a vector called "data":

```
sample = rnorm(2093)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample, nrow=91, ncol=23))
```

After, I named the lines with a vector called "name":

```
name = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23")
```

Lastly, I used the "lapply" function to scroll through the data:

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~data[1])

aux_list_1 <- lapply(seq_along(data), function(j){
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~data[[j]], name = name[j],type='scatter',mode = 'lines')
  fig
  })

fig
```

When i ran "fig" showed the follow error:

> No trace type specified:
>    Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
>    Read more about this trace type -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#histogram

Or, when i ran "aux_list_1" the plots were separated.

Follows the full code:

```
sample = rnorm(2093)
data<- as.data.frame(matrix(random,nrow=91,ncol=23))

name = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23")

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~data[1])

aux_list_1 <- lapply(seq_along(data), function(j){
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~data[[j]], name = name[j],type='scatter',mode = 'lines')
  fig
  })

fig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~data[1])

for(trace in colnames(data))
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = as.formula(paste0("~", trace)), 
                             name = trace, type='scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig
```

---

[image]